# Remove a uiview once a table view cell is tapped (swift)

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uiview

I have a custom xib table view cell that has a green uiview on it. The uiview acts as a new message indicator - whenever a message comes in, the green view is displayed. When a user taps the cell, I want to set the view to hidden. My only question is; how would I go about hiding the view just on that specific table view cell and not all table view cells?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your model

```
class Item {
   var greenHidden = false
   /// more properties
}
```

Then create  the green view inside the xib and according to the current state do inside `cellForRowAt`

```
 let cell = //
 let item = arr[indexPath.row]
 cell.greenView.isHidden = item.greenHidden
```

When the cell is tapped inside `didSelectRowAt` do

```
arr[indexPath.row].greenHidden = true
self.tableView.reloadRows(at:[indexPath],with:.none)
```